# Does Angular Material have built in autosizing for textareas?

Tags: angular, textarea, angular-material, autosize

I am able to import MatTextareaAutosize from Angular Material, but I see nothing about it in the [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview) and have not found a way to use it.

I expected to use something like this:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <textarea matInput matAutosize></textarea>
</mat-form-field>
```

Is there a way to get autosizing text boxes with angular material?

Comment: note: it can screw up the scrollbar if not at 100% zoom (amongst other conditions) - Possible solutions here https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/12902

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer is simple: it should be `matTextareaAutosize`, not just `matAutosize`: https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/material-examples/input-autosize-textarea/input-autosize-textarea-example.html

Caution! Apparently, this will be removed in version 7 and is currently deprecated
https://material.angular.io/components/input/api#MatTextareaAutosize

*PS: See also comment from @Simon_Weaver regarding the deprecation*

Comment: Thanks, that is simple. Good to know about those examples as well.

Comment: Regarding the deprecation : `<textarea> elements can be made to automatically resize by using the cdkTextareaAutosize directive available in the CDK.` So you're supposed to use that.

Comment: ...Although nothing is ever simple and I get leftover scrollbars even at 100% zoom level :-( It's off by one pixel! It'll set a height of 108px and I'll change it to 109% and they'll go away.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/8050f633b56b6c048fc72dad2ab79304afdfad19/src/material-examples/text-field-autosize-textarea/text-field-autosize-textarea-example.html

Answer (score 18):

For my work apply this to `textarea`:

**Angular 7**

```
<textarea cdkTextareaAutosize #autosize="cdkTextareaAutosize"cdkAutosizeMinRows="1" cdkAutosizeMaxRows="5"> </textarea>
```

Verify the **scroll**, in case of not showing verify the **CSS** property `'overflow: auto'`

Comment: Also don't forget to import the TextFieldModule from cdk in your module: import { TextFieldModule } from '@angular/cdk/text-field';

Comment: Thank you, @Nadine! All the examples and documentation assumed `matInput` would also be on the textarea, and I couldn't find the cdk module to import if I was just using cdk.

Comment: This worked for me without having to import the ```TextFieldModule``` in my module. Also I didn't have to use the attribute ```#autosize="cdkTextareaAutosize"```, also could someone tell me what is the importance of using this attribute or selector?
Finally this is how my final code looked:
```<textarea cdkTextareaAutosize cdkAutosizeMinRows="2" cdkAutosizeMaxRows="5" matInput></textarea>```

Comment: Also here's a stackBlitz example of textarea autosizing https://stackblitz.com/angular/pbadbpbgyog?file=app%2Ftext-field-autosize-textarea-example.html

Comment: This is a very nice option but it makes the typing very slow